# spawn random objects around but not on player

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I am making a simple shooter game in javascript for a school project.
Im quite new to Javascript so I bump into some problems so now and then.
I figured out how to spawn random objects every x seconds but I can't find out how to make them spawn lets say atleast 50px away from me/the player.

I have tried changing the values of the x and y of my objects but it did not work out. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

```js
  var 
 canvas,
  ctx,
  width = 960,
  height = 540,
  rightKey = false,
  leftKey = false,
  upKey = false,
  downKey = false,
  player_x = 480,
 player_y = 270, 
 player_w = 30, 
 player_h = 30,
  bulletTotal = 3,
  bullet = [],
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
 spawnRate = 1500,
 spawnRateOfDescent = 0.50,
 lastSpawn = -1,
 objects = [];


function spawnRandomObject() {
   
    var c = "red";
 
    var object = {  
        x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 70) + 15,     
        y: Math.random() * (canvas.height - 70) + 15
    }
    objects.push(object);
}

function animate() {
  
    var time = Date.now();
  //I tried adding this disctance var but it gives an error
 var distance = (player_x - object.x)^2 + (player_y - object.y)^2;
   
    if (time > (lastSpawn + spawnRate)) {
        lastSpawn = time;
        spawnRandomObject();
    }
// here I tried to spawn a new object if it was in 50px of the player. 
 if (distance < 2500){
  spawnRandomObject();
 }
 
 
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "3";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
        ctx.rect(object.x, object.y, 40,40);
        ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "3";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
    }
}
animate();


function clearCanvas() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
 }



function drawplayer() {
 if (rightKey) player_x += 5;
 else if (leftKey) player_x -= 5;
 if (upKey) player_y -= 5;
 else if (downKey) player_y += 5;
 if (player_x <= 30) player_x = 30;
 if ((player_x + player_w) >= width) player_x = width - player_w;
  if (player_y <= 30) player_y = 30;
 if ((player_y + player_h) >= height) player_y = height - player_h;
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = "3";
 ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
 ctx.arc(player_x, player_y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
 
}


function drawbullet() {
  if (bullet.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
     ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
     ctx.fillRect(bullet[i].x -18,bullet[i].y - 20, bullet[i].width ,bullet[i].height)
   }
}
function movebullet() {
 for (var i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
   bullet[i].x += bullet[i].speedX;
   bullet[i].y += bullet[i].speedY;
   if(bullet[i].x < 0 || bullet[i].x > width ||
     bullet[i].y < 0 || bullet[i].y > height) bullet.splice(i, 1);
 }
}

function init() {
 //canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 //ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 setInterval(gameLoop, 25);
 document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
 document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);
}
function gameLoop() {
 clearCanvas();
 movebullet();
 drawplayer();
 drawbullet();
}

function keyDown(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 68) rightKey = true;
 else if (e.keyCode == 65) leftKey = true;
 if (e.keyCode == 87) upKey = true;
 else if (e.keyCode == 83) downKey = true;
 if (e.keyCode == 32 && bullet.length <= bulletTotal) {
   let b = {
     x: player_x + player_w/2, y: player_y + player_h/2, speedX: 0, speedY: 0, width: 20, height: 20
   };
   if(rightKey) {
     b.x += player_w;
     b.speedX += 20;
     b.height = 5;
   }
   if(upKey) {
     b.y -= player_h;
     b.speedY -= 20;
     b.width = 5;
   }
   if(downKey && b.speedY === 0) {
     b.y += player_h;
     b.speedY += 20;
     b.width = 5;
   }
   if(b.speedX === 0 && (leftKey || b.speedY === 0)) {
     b.x -= player_w;
     b.speedX -= 20;
     b.height = 5;
   }
   bullet.push(b);
 }
}

function keyUp(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 68) rightKey = false;
 else if (e.keyCode == 65) leftKey = false;
 if (e.keyCode == 87) upKey = false;
 else if (e.keyCode == 83) downKey = false;
}

//window.onload = init;
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
 background-color:  #000066; 
}

canvas {
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3cc;
   position: absolute;
   left: 25%;
   top: 25%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="540"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check for the distance with the player while spawning using the distance formula: `distance = (player.x - box.x)^2 + (player.y - box.y)^2`. If this distance is smaller than `(player.width/2)^2 + (box.width/2)^2) * sqrt(2)`, there is a "collision". find another random position to place the box now. (The width of the box is multiplied by sqrt(2) because the box is a square).

Comment: If you want to maintain a distance of 50px from the player, then check if `(player.x - box.x)^2 + (player.y - box.y)^2<2500` or not (Pythagorean formula). If it is, get another random coordinate to place the box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, ill try to make it work!:)

Comment: I tried to use the distance formula but I think i used it wrong, I've updated my code i used above. Sorry for the questions really struggeling with coding atm.

Answer (score 0):

For **2D platform games** you can use this code:

Here is a simple way of generating random number with excluding ranges.

```js
var randomEx = function (start, end, excludeArray) {
  var regions = excludeArray.length + 1;
  var region = parseInt(Math.random() * regions);
  var regionStart = start;
  if (region > 0) regionStart = excludeArray[region - 1][1];
  var regionEnd = end;
  if (region < excludeArray.length) regionEnd = excludeArray[region][0];
  var range = regionEnd - regionStart;
  return (regionStart + (Math.random() * range));
};

var click = function () {
  var start = Number(document.querySelector('#start').value);
  var end = Number(document.querySelector('#end').value);
  var excludeArray = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#ex').value);
  var random = randomEx(start, end, excludeArray);
  document.querySelector('p').textContent = random;
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', click);

click();
```

```html
Start: <input id="start" value="2"/><br>
End: <input id="end" value="10"/><br>
Exclude: <input id="ex" value="[[3,5],[7,8]]"/><br>
<p></p>
<button>Random</button><br>
```

Here is how it works, let's imagine the following example:

`start = 2; end = 10; exclude from 3 to 5 and from 7 to 8`

Imagine a line with our excluded ranges marked as `x`

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    ---------xxxxxx------xxx--------
     region1      region2   region3
```

As you can see, that creates 3 regions for us to place our random number. So let's first choose one of this regions randomly. Let's suppose the hardest scenario: our picked region is `region2`.

So our regionStart will be the first excluded range's end (the number 5) and our regionEnd will be the last excluded range's start (the number 7).

Now we just need to calculate the `range` of our region: `regionEnd - regionStart`, and our random number will be `regionStart + (Math.random() * range)`. In other words, our random number will begin at our regionStart plus anything from 0 to the calculated range.

**Note** that this algorithm will make smaller regions more filled with units since the code do not consider the distribution. If you need a **linear distribution** use this code instead: https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/yRzvEM

For games where the units have both x and y position, this code is an option: https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/KGXrBR?editors=0010